# i am trying to convert a string number to int but it coudn't work

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to convert a string number to int in visual studio, but whenever I do it shows me an error.

```
"c:\Users\USER\Desktop\Appbrewery_course\Day_5\Average_height_exercise.py", line 5, in <module>
        student_heights[i] = int(student_heights[i])
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '180,'
```

Here is the below code i have written.

```
    #  Don't change the code below 
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split()
print(student_heights)
for i in range(0,len(student_heights)):
    student_heights[i] = int(student_heights[i])
#  Don't change the code above 
print(type(student_heights[0]))
```

Comment: Either don't enter the comma, or remove it.

Comment: `.split()` doesn't know you've passed a comma-separated list, so they're still in the resulting strings, which can't be parsed as `int`.

Comment: @KlausD. Thanks dear, I did a little mistake. I didn't pass the argument into the split() function. I sitting almost 1 hour to fix these bugs.

Answer (score 0):

```
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split()
```

This line takes a string and splits it whenever it encounters a space. Make sure to seperate the input string with spaces rather than any other character.

*For example, with the current setup, input string should look like :*
`100 200 300 400 500`

*and **not** like :*
`100,200,300,400`

Your code is correct, just enter the input string according to your input method as mentioned above.

**EDIT: If you want to use a comma seperated input string (i.e `100,200,300,400`) then change line 5 to :**

```
student_heights = input("Input a list of student heights ").split(",")
```